# WPF DataGrid Printer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, printing

I have a pretty long and wide datagrid which I would like to send to the printer. But how do I print it when I want all rows and columns. It may fill multiple pages - that doesn't matter.

I am using WPF, C# and .Net 4.0

### Here is my datagrid

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="1"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}"
              Name="dataGrid"
              LoadingRow="dataGrid_LoadingRow" 
              MouseMove="dataGrid_MouseMove">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Task ID" CellTemplate="{StaticResource hyperlinkTemplate}"></DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=TaskName}" Header="Task name" />
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=TaskResponsible}" Header="Task responsible" />
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=TaskResponsibleDepartment}" Header="Task responsible department"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Category, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" Header="Category" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource CellEditStyle}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Status, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" Header="Status" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource CellEditStyle}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Priority, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" Header="Priority" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource CellEditStyle}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=StartDate, StringFormat={}{0:yyyy MMMM dd}}" Header="Start date"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=ActualHours.TotalHours, StringFormat={}{0:0}}" Header="Actual hours" />
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=EstimatedHours.TotalHours, StringFormat={}{0:0}}" Header="Estimated hours" />
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=EstimatedDeploymentDate, StringFormat={}{0:yyyy MMMM dd}}" Header="Estimated deployment date" />
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=DesiredImplementationDate, StringFormat={}{0:yyyy MMMM dd}}" Header="Desired deployment date" />
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=APP.StartDate, StringFormat={}{0:yyyy MMMM dd}}" Header="APP - Start Date"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=APP.EstimatedHours}" Header="APP - Estimated hours"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=APP.ActualHours}" Header="APP - Actual hours"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=IN.StartDate, StringFormat={}{0:yyyy MMMM dd}}" Header="IN - Start Date"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=IN.EstimatedHours}" Header="IN - Estimated hours"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=IN.ActualHours}" Header="IN - Actual hours"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=SIS.StartDate, StringFormat={}{0:yyyy MMMM dd}}" Header="SIS - Start Date"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=SIS.EstimatedHours}" Header="SIS - Estimated hours"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=SIS.ActualHours}" Header="SIS - Actual hours"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Tags}" Header="Tags"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Did you think about using FlowDocument and it\`s Table control? It has better printing capabilities, AFAIK.

Comment: Do you know about a good tutorial to learn how to use the document?

Comment: Well, [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909.aspx) has nice article about that (and [Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747133.aspx) too). Other than that, I can only suggest googling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just answering this question for @icebat. This can be done with the flow document tool.